# Python pandas list of objects to DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a built-in way to convert a list of objects in Python to a Pandas DataFrame.

```
myList = [
    {
        name:'ABC',
        value:35,
        date:2018-01-01
    },
    {
        name:'ABC',
        value:30,
        date:2018-01-02
    },
    {
        name:'DEF',
        value:70,
        date:2018-01-01
    },
    {
        name:'DEF',
        value:22,
        date:2018-01-02
    }
]
```

Convert to

[image]

Comment: Please make sure what you post here is pastable into an interpreter. I don't want to add quotes for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert your data pretty easily to a dataframe, and then `pivot` to achieve the layout you desire:

```
import pandas as pd

myList = [{"name":'ABC', "value":35, "date":"2018-01-01"},{"name":'ABC', "value":30, "date":"2018-01-02"},{"name":'DEF', "value":70, "date":"2018-01-01"},{"name":'DEF', "value":22, "date":"2018-01-02"}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=myList)
df = df.pivot(index = "date", columns = "name")
```

```py
>>> df
           value    
name         ABC DEF
date                
2018-01-01    35  70
2018-01-02    30  22
```